# Drum brake shoes question

Tags: brakes, emergency-brakes

Hi guys I had my rear drum brakes replaced about a month ago. All new hardware, shoes, drums.

Now my rear passenger ones are making a clicking noise at very low speeds.

Took the drum off to examine and noticed the front left shoe retaining clip could be moved with my hand with a fair amount of force but not strong arming it. The other shoe didn't have the same movement .

Now my question is, how tight should the shoes be held in place to the backing plate? Should the spring and clip be able to slide around with a fair amount of force from your hand or do they need to be held in pretty solid? [image: drum]

Update: Examined both sides at same time and only difference I could see was the bottom return springs weren't hooked up the same (hook ends are reversed) would that cause a click click sound? I've narrowed down the noise to the passenger side and that's the bottom half of the pic[image: 2]

Comment: If the shoe is in a bind, it will be harder to rotate the retainer clip, remove the drum and they should move freely. It does not matter if they can move, all they do is keep the brake shoe retainer pin from falling out and keep the brake shoe from moving out of place.

Comment: But are they supposed to be held in place pretty firmly or doesn't matter? Trying to determine if that's what's causing the clicking noise I've been hearing from the rear brakes

Comment: All they do is keep the shoes in place during assembly. Clicking can be caused by out of round or warped drums, have them turned on on a brake lathe or replace them.

Comment: Definitely as Moab stated. The clip is just there to hold it together. It should be firm but allow for movement. The brake shoes have to move in order to work correctly.

Comment: So the clicking would only happen with a warped drum? They're brand new along with hardware

Comment: Technically, the place where the shoes rub against the backing plate is supposed to be greased.  Those clips do nothing but hold the whole assembly together appropriately.  What I suspect is the *adjustment*, or something not specifically brake related.

Comment: @SteveRacer I greased the three points behind the shoes on the backing plate today. Didn't do much still makes the click noise. My ebrake stops clicking around 4-5 clicks but the brakes make a creak noise as little as 1 click when engaging. How should they be adjusted exactly? I've tried turning star wheel so drum just barely drags

Comment: @ohmmy  That sounds like a reasonable adjsutment, but I like to either adjust out until the drum  is locked and frozen, and then back off until the shoes drag a medium amount.  Or, you can stomp he brake pedal as they start to drag, and add a few more clicks.  The key is getting the show assembly (it floats) perfectly centered.  (also, I like to install a couple lugnuts to keep drum tight against hub) In any case, if it's close, it shouldn't click.  Recheck drum interiors, make sure no return springs are loose, including that braided cable thing on the adjuster stay.

Comment: @SteveRacer braided cable thing? Also if the adjustment was close wouldn't the self adjuster take care of it?

Comment: @ohmmy   I forget the name (beleive me; I'm embarrased).  It's usually a washer that's buried below the center pivot pin,  connected to a braided cable to the pivot lever that does the self-adjusting...  by indexing the starwheel forward.  Typically, these work when braking in reverse only.  So you might want to reverse in a quiet parking lot and stomp the brakes a few dozen times.  Still, I suspect now there's more to this problem.  Good luck.  I'll be here until the gin runs out...

Comment: I've uploaded a second pic comparing the bottom return spring on both sides wondering if it matters which way the hooks are clipped in to the shoes because they're not the same

Comment: Btw the drag you hear while spinning is it supposed to be uninterrupted? With mine the drag is every about half a turn. Wonder if drums are warped